# NewtonSoft JSON Add JObject to JObject

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I currently have the below:

```
Dim persons_dr = dt_driverdetails.Select("[B@] = '2' and [PolRef@] = 'YOLX14PC01'")

Dim rss As JObject = New JObject(New JProperty("people"))

For Each row As DataRow In persons_dr

    Dim person As person = New person With {
    .person_id = row("person_id").ToString,
    .email = row("email").ToString,
    .mobile = row("mobile").ToString,
    .forename = row("forename").ToString,
    .surname = row("surname").ToString
    }

    Dim o As JObject = CType(JToken.FromObject(person), JObject)

rss.Add(New JProperty(o, New JObject()))

Next
```

There can be multiple `person` object described in the `people` array.
The `For Each` loop generates a new JObject for each `person`. I want to add them all to the `rss` JObject, so that my JObject ends up being like the below example:

```
{
    "people": [{
        "person_id": "71DLUOBNERUA1002",
        "email": "test1@gmail.com",
        "mobile": "+4412345678",
        "forename": "John",
        "surname": "Hopkins"

    },
    {
        "person_id": "71DLUOBNERUA1002",
        "email": "test1@gmail.com",
        "mobile": "+4412345678",
        "forename": "John",
        "surname": "Hopkins"
    }]
}
```

However, I receive an error: *Object cannot be converted to String*.
I assume this is because I've used JProperty.

Any advice would be great - ideally someone telling me where I've gone wrong rather than just correcting my code - keen to learn :)

**UPDATE**

```
Public Class person
    Public Property person_id As String
    Public Property email As String
    Public Property mobile As String
    Public Property forename As String
    Public Property surname As String
End Class

Public Class people
    Public Property persons As List(Of person)
End Class

Private Sub create_person_json()

        Dim persons_dr = dt_driverdetails.Select("[B@] = '2' and [PolRef@] = 'YOLX14PC01'")
        Dim people As New people
        'Dim rss As JObject = New JObject(New JProperty("people"))

        For Each row As DataRow In persons_dr

            Dim person As person = New person With {
            .person_id = row("person_id").ToString,
            .email = row("email").ToString,
            .mobile = row("mobile").ToString,
            .forename = row("forename").ToString,
            .surname = row("surname").ToString
            }

            people.persons.Add(person)

            'Dim o As JObject = CType(JToken.FromObject(person), JObject)
        Next


    End Sub
```

**UPDATE 2**

If I wanted to nest another set of JSON into the list like below:

```
    "people": [{
        "person_id": "71DLUOBNERUA1002",
        "email": "test1@gmail.com",
        "mobile": "+4412345678",
        "forename": "John",
        "surname": "Hopkins"
    "address": {
        "line_1": "76 This Place",
        "postal_code": "BB11 8DL",
        "country": "GB"
    },
}]
```

Could I do the following my classes:

```
Public Class person
    Public Property person_id As String
    Public Property email As String
    Public Property mobile As String
    Public Property forename As String
    Public Property surname As String
    Public Property address As New address()
    Public Property dob As String
    'Public Property driverdetails As New driver_details()
End Class

Public Class address
    Public Property line_1 As String
    Public Property town_city As String
    Public Property postal_code As String
    Public Property country As String
End Class
```

Then how I would I get that into my existing code as I can't add it into the "person" object because I'd need to initialize the class first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of a .Net class *model* that describes the JSON, makes it simpler to handle the Property values and objects creation: it's much simpler than working with JTokens and derived objects.

The `<JsonProperty()>` attribute allows to use Property names in the class model that are different from the JSON's. It's often used when JSON properties use names that are reserved words in a language or when deemed necessary/preferable.
The Json serializer (or deserializer) will match the class model's Properties names with the specified attributes.

See also:

- [Serialization Attributes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm).
- [JsonPropertyAttribute name](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm)

The JSON structure shown in the question can be reproduced using the following model:
<sub>Note: the names here are changed to show the use of the `<JsonProperty()>` attribute.</sub>

```
Public Class PeopleRoot
    <JsonProperty("people")>
    Public Property People As List(Of Person) = New List(Of Person)
End Class

Public Class Person
    <JsonProperty("person_id")>
    Public Property PersonId As String
    <JsonProperty("email")>
    Public Property Email As String
    <JsonProperty("mobile")>
    Public Property Mobile As String
    <JsonProperty("forename")>
    Public Property FirstName As String
    <JsonProperty("surname")>
    Public Property Surname As String
    <JsonProperty("address")>
    Public Property Address As PersonAddress
End Class

Public Class PersonAddress
    Public Property line_1 As String
    Public Property town_city As String
    Public Property postal_code As String
    Public Property country As String
End Class
```

To initialize the `PeopleRoot.People` Property as a `List(Of Person)`, simply declare a new `PeopleRoot` object:

```
Dim root As New PeopleRoot()

' Add new Person objects:
root.People.AddRange({
    New Person With {
        .PersonId = "ID1",
        .Email = "email1@service1.com",
        .Mobile = "12345678",
        .FirstName = "Person1",
        .Surname = "Surname1",
        .Address = New PersonAddress() With {
            .line_1 = "Line1", .town_city = "Town1", .postal_code = "12345", .country = "Country1"
        }
    },
    New Person With {
        .PersonId = "ID2",
        .Email = "email2@service2.com",
        .Mobile = "34567890",
        .FirstName = "Person2",
        .Surname = "Surname2",
        .Address = New PersonAddress() With {
            .line_1 = "Line2", .town_city = "Town2", .postal_code = "34567", .country = "Country2"
        }
    }
})

' Serialize the new values
Dim json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root)
```

This structure is serialized as the original JSON:

```
{
   "people":[
      {
         "person_id":"ID1",
         "email":"email1@service1.com",
         "mobile":"12345678",
         "forename":"Person1",
         "surname":"Surname1",
         "address":{
            "line_1":"Line1",
            "town_city":"Town1",
            "postal_code":"12345",
            "country":"Country1"
         }
      },
      {
         "person_id":"ID2",
         "email":"email2@service2.com",
         "mobile":"34567890",
         "forename":"Person2",
         "surname":"Surname2",
         "address":{
            "line_1":"Line2",
            "town_city":"Town2",
            "postal_code":"34567",
            "country":"Country2"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

which of course can be deserialized as:

```
Dim obJPeople = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of PeopleRoot)(jsonString)
```

Comment: Using your method above, if a value doesn't exist and I'm pulling the information from DataRow from a DataTable - how can I set it to "Nothing" so that if the data doesn't exist it doesn't create the element. I've got NullValueHandling.Ignore set in the SerializeObject settings, how do I set the default value of all my entries to "Nothing" so that they don't don't appear after serialization.

Comment: You need to post another question, adding the details of your operations. It's not really clear what you're asking here.